# Checking if JSON is convertible to c# class

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I wanted something like this

```
public object LoadFromConfig(Type type, string sectionName)
{
  try 
  {
     serializedJson = //fetch and serialize the Json from given sectionName
     return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serializedJson, type,
     JsonSerializerSettings);

  }
  //was expecting this exception if serializedJson is not convertible to type.
  catch(ArgumentException e)
  {

    return null;

  }
```

`DeserializedObject` is returning the empty object of type `type` in case if `serializedJson` is not a match for the `type`. I want to return `null` in this case. Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean, *if `serializedJson` is not a match for the `type`*?  Is there a `"$type"` property specifying a type not assignable to `type`?  Or are there simply no properties in common between `type` and the actual properties in the JSON?  Can you [edit] your question to share a concrete [mcve]?  By default [json](http://www.json.org/) objects are **untyped** -- they are simply an *an unordered set of name/value pairs*.  Json.NET will deserialize a JSON to your desired type by matching up the c# and JSON properties by name.

Answer (score 0):

@YakRangi, I think Jacob is giving you a good point with the generic type, you should create your classes that match the equivalent of the json that you are expecting and then call the

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serializedJson, JsonSerializerSettings);
```

Now let's say that the json that you are expecting has a property `password` that is a string, then create your class as this

```
class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty("password")]
    public string Password
}
```

then you have a

```
try
{
    var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(serializedJson, JsonSerializerSettings);
}
catch
{
    return null;
}
```

Hope this helps